# liunx bash echo 4096 bytes to a file, file using 8 bytes on disk?

Tags: bash, filesystems

when I use bash to write a temp test file on liunx terminal.

```
echo text_content>file1
```

if set length of text_content 4096 char(random char from [a-Z]) long.
the result file1 ends up use two 4K blocks. and one inode.

```
test@instance-7:~/notes/rust$ du -csh file1
8.0K    file1
8.0K    totaldu
```

But why it used two 4K blocks? I mean, Isn't one 4K block is enough for it?

if I set the length of the text_content 4095 char long, it used only one 4K block.

why it's using more blocks for it needed? or I'm missing something?

here are some disk info for my liunx machine.

```
test@instance-7:~/notes/rust$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Disk model: PersistentDisk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gptDisk identifier: 35BD657D-931E-497E-A86C-D3D7C4F6BD2A
```

Comment: `echo` adds a linebreak. Try `echo -n`.

Comment: @tkausl So If I write by myself instead of echo this is solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this experiment:

- write `cat > file1` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
- then write `this` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice **without hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> first**;
- write `cat > file2` and hit <kbd>Enter,</kbd>
- then write `this`, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then Ctrl-D.
- finally run `diff file1 file2` and `ls -l file[12]`

Comment: I found that hexdump -C is really help too.